# I am using setTimeout and fetch API both, bot didn't understand which one will execute first?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, event-loop

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("Callback after delay")
},1000)

setTimeout(()=>{
  console.log("Callback with no delay")
})

console.log("HI this is test")
```

It is giving the below output:

```
HI this is test
Callback with no delay
{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
Callback with delay
```

As callback in promises goes to `microtask queue` then callback in `fetch` should be execute first and after that setTimeout code with `no delay` and then `delay`

Comment: Async code executes when it finishes, not in the order you initialize the async request. Async code does not execute top to bottom, it's **asynchronous**, it executes when it finishes, long after your top level code runs. This exact question is asked several dozen times a day on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetch`, `setTimeout` both runs asynchronously.

The difference is that --

There is no guaranteed time when the response will come back from `fetch`. The code in then will execute when the response is received (when the Promise is resolved).

However, in case of `setTimeout`, you provide the timeout. The internal Web APIs of the browser runs a timer of the given duration (milliseconds). After the timer times out, your code will get executed. In your case you have two `setTimeout` - one with 0 ms, another 1000 ms. So, first you'll see `"Callback with no delay"`, then after one second `"Callback after delay"`.

`console.log()` runs like synchronous code. So the moment this line executed you'll see the `"HI this is test"` text on console.

You're seeing this order, because the `fetch` response came back before 1 second. The placement of `fetch` response will vary depending on the speed of the network, and response time from the server.

```
HI this is test
Callback with no delay
{userId: 1, id: 1, title: 'delectus aut autem', completed: false}
Callback with delay
```

However, these two messages will always be at the top in the same order:

```
HI this is test
Callback with no delay
```

I hope the explanation was clear!

Comment: thanks for the clear explanation for this confusing concept. It is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

as @Andy mentioned, The `fetch` and `setTimeout` are asynchronous, and will execute when it finished, so for example if the `fetch` method took more than one second to get the `data` it will execute after the `setTimeout` after delay.

If you want the `fetch` method execute first and then the `setTimeout` you need to `await` it.

```
(async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  const result = await response.json();
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Callback after delay")
  },1000)

  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log("Callback with no delay")
  })

  console.log("HI this is test")
 
})
```

Now the `fetch` will execute the first one.